# What's the best way to provide different behaviors in different environments in Angular?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

We've got a certain behavior related to the redirect after user login that we need to versions of:

One for production, that is related to the external login service, and one for prod, that uses the internal login service.

The first solution we came up with as putting each in a different file, and using angular.json to replace one with the other when it's in production.

The solution ended up being something like this in angular.json:

```
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            },               {
              "replace": "behavior.dev.ts",
              "with": "behavior.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
```

This sparked certain worries about this being a good solution, best practices wise, and others suggested that we use providers and dependency injection, but I was wondering if there's other ways other than these two, and what would be considered the best practice regarding this.

Comment: The magic word is [environment](https://blog.angulartraining.com/how-to-manage-different-environments-with-angular-cli-883c26e99d15).

Comment: @MarkusZeller Right, the second solution (through providers and dependency injection) that we've thought of  I'd have to create a factory, and inside the factory I'd be using the environment.production to see which of the instances I'd need. Is this a good solution?

Comment: I'd generally recommend runtime configuration, rather than the build time configuration of Angular environments; I blogged about it [here](https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html).

Comment: Nice article Jon!